# How do I store this data set in C++ (which containers do I use)?

Tags: c++, vector, set, containers

I have data represented as follows.

```
A-> B,C,D,E,F
B-> C,(D,E),F
D-> (E,F)
E-> (F,G)
F-> (G)
G-> NULL
```

Each letter represents a string.  All letters/strings are in alphabetical order.  The B->  means that B is a member of every element succeeding it.  So for this example row B consists of the sets (B,C), (B,D,E) and (B,F).  Each row can only contain strings higher in order then the row string.  I have to arrange the data this way.

Should I use a sequence container like vector or an associative container like set.

I am building small clusters to make big clusters, so I will be iterating through all the data starting from the bottom up.

My guess would be a set of sets?

Comment: If you plan on iterating through the data from one end to the other in a predictable manner and want to store jagged arrays, a list of lists sounds like a good idea. Only problem is sorting...

Comment: Do letters represent actual strings, like multi-character strings, or just a pointer to character like `const char *`?

Comment: They represent actual strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems a graph is what you are looking for, but the standard C++ library (STL) does not have such a data structure. The next best bet is multimap: a map is an 1:1 associated array, where as multimap is a 1:many associated array.

Comment: No, you can look up the 1 part (AKA the key) using the find() method, but not the many part (AKA the values).

Comment: Ended up going with a map of sets

Answer (score 0):

I'd say use a hashtable, where each string maps to a vector and in turn each vector element points to another vector.

So something like this:

```
"b" -> {{"a", "b"},{"d"},{"e"}}
```